# how to move second line of text in list item to the right

Tags: html, css

Here is a inner section of a page :

[image]

The word `office` is falling right under the fontawesome icon and I want it to align with the text above it.

Code snippet:

```css
.tabcontent {
  float: left;
  padding: 100px 30px;
  border: none;
  width: 33%;
  border-left: none;
  height: 580px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px white, 0 6px white, -5px -9px 8px 4px #88888878, 5px -9px 8px 4px #88888878;
}

#ctab2 p,
#ctab4 p {
  display: inline;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" integrity="sha512-5A8nwdMOWrSz20fDsjczgUidUBR8liPYU+WymTZP1lmY9G6Oc7HlZv156XqnsgNUzTyMefFTcsFH/tnJE/+xBg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div id="ctab2" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Place of Service</h3>
  <h5>Application Submission</h5>
  <i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i>
  <p>&nbsp&nbspSharjah Ports Website</p>
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
  <p>24 x 7</p><br><br>
  <h5>Processing & Approval</h5>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i></td>
    <td>
      <p>&nbsp&demo123 game Security & jikoi Dept. &nbsp; &nbsp; Office</p>
    </td>
  </tr><br>
  <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
  <p>Monday – Thursday, 07:30 – 15:30</p><br><br>

</div>
```

Comment: CSS-Grid will solve the issue.

Comment: You've got a partial table in there that's not best practice - the information you've put in the code looks like it has been scraped from somewhere, rather than copying the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

you can use flexbox and put two elements in row, center the elements vertical

```
    .container {
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.icon {
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    margin: 4px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
}

.container-text { 
    margin: 0
}
```

css above and html

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <p class="container-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
    At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
    consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo
    dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Replace the icon with your icon.
Don't use tr and td elements without table element, use some other elements like div or section

Don't use &nbsp in your p element, use margin or padding in css of the p element instead

Answer (score 0):

there are different solutions. one of them is using the display flex.
but anyway good work. i would have stayed away from the float though. it may cause alot of issues for display.
also  and  should just be used inside

```css
.tabcontent {
    float: left;
    padding: 100px 30px;
    border:none;
    width: 33%;
    border-left: none;
    height: 580px;
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow:0 -6px white,
        0 6px white, -5px -9px 8px 4px #88888878, 5px -9px 8px 4px #88888878;
    }

#ctab2 p,#ctab4 p
        {display: inline;
            color: #000;
        }
.custom-wrapper { display: flex;flex-direction:row;}
.custom-wrapper > .fa {display:inline-block;}
.custom-wrapper > p {margin:0'}
```

```html
<div id="ctab2" class="tabcontent">
    <h3>Place of Service</h3>
    <h5>Application Submission</h5>
    <i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i>
    <p>&nbsp&nbspSharjah Ports Website</p>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <p>24 x 7</p><br><br>
    <h5>Processing & Approval</h5>
    <div class="custom-wrapper">
    <i class="fa fa-map-pin"></i>
    <p>&nbsp&demo123 game Security & jikoi Dept. &nbsp; &nbsp; Office</p>
</div>
<br>
    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
    <p>Monday – Thursday, 07:30 – 15:30</p><br><br>

    </div>
```